# Passing parameter with slash (/) changing navbar menu item html link also in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

When I pass parameter after slashing e.g URL `Resume/Index/1323142424123` it changes the navbar menu item URL means add that parameter also into the navbar URL but when I pass parameters like `Resume/Index?id=1323142424123` it did not change the navbar link.

My HTML markup is

```
<a asp-area="JobSeeker" asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Resume">Profile</a>
```

I checked my code there is no such javascript code that is changing the navbar link.

**Note:** I m using the razor component on this page.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the asp.net core tag helper will render the url's route parameter in the herf. This is by-design.

If you don't want to avoid adding the route parameter, I suggest you could add the
empty route data.

E.g:

If your route like below:

```
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=home}/{action=index}/{id?}");

        });
```

The id is the route parameter. Then you should use your tag helper like below:

```
<a  asp-action="Link" asp-controller="Home"  asp-route-id="">Profile</a>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This works for me by adding the empty route data e.g `<a  asp-action="Link" asp-controller="Home"  asp-route-id="">Profile</a>`.